# Why code doesn't work on using pre/post increment operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

The below code is about finding duplicate value in the given vector. When I am using the post/pre increment operator instead of normal arithmetic operation used below, it's not working. What might be the reason??

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
        int d=0;
        auto it1=nums.begin();
        auto it2=nums.end();
        vector<int>::iterator it3;

        while (it1 != it2)
        {
            it3 = it1 + 1; //it3=it1++ or it3=++it1 ;

            while (it3 != it2)
            {
                if (*(it3)==*(it1))
                {
                    d=*(it3);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    it3++;
            }

            if(d)
              break;

            it1 += 1;  //it1++ or ++it1;
        }

        return d;
    }
};
```

Comment: `it3=it1++` and `it3=it1+1;` do two different things. The first modifies `it1` the second doesn't

Comment: `if(d)` won't work if your duplicate value is a 0. (in addition to Sheep's comment above about your actual question)

Comment: it3=it1++ it3 becomes it1 while it3=++it1 it3 becomes it1+1 so what is your problem. Why do you believe it ist PRE and POST incremt. PRE and POST what? :-)

Comment: `it3=it1++` means `it3 = it1; it1 += 1`, `it3=++it1` means `it1 += 1; it3 = it1`, neither of which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
it1+=1;  //it1++ or ++it1;
```

This will work with either pre- or post-increment. Since you're not doing anything with the incremented `it1`, it doesn't matter which you use here. Any 3 of these options will work.

```
it3=it1+1; //it3=it1++ or it3=++it1 ;
```

This is where the behavior really changes

```
it3 = it1 + 1;
```

Does what you want. It sets `it3` to one-past `it1` and does not modify `it1`.

```
it3 = ++it1;
```

This also sets `it3` to one-past `it1`, but in the process, it increments `it1` as well, which you do not want.

```
it3 = it1++;
```

This is the worst of the bunch. It sets `it3` to `it1` (NOT one-past), and then after, increments `it1`. So nothing ends up with the values you want.

If you really wanted to use the increment operator here, you could do

```
(it3 = it1)++;
```

This would give `it3` `it1`'s value, and then increment `it3`. But this is pretty ugly. There's no real reason to deviate from `it3 = it1 + 1;`.